# How to use 'implements' function in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm just starting to learn Android development, and I'm currently following through thenewboston's Android tutorials. I don't know why i get this error:

```
Error:(10, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFling(MotionEvent,MotionEvent,float,float) in OnGestureListener
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.gonzales.gestures;

import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

//the error is because of this
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

This is almost the exact code as in the tutorial. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you need to implement `onFling(MotionEvent,MotionEvent,float,float)` method which is defined in `OnGestureListener` interface. Extends is used for class extension and implements for interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared that you've implemented interfaces, and this obliges you to implement those interfaces' methods, which you haven't done.

As a bare minimum to deal with the immediate error, you need to implement:

```
onFling(MotionEvent, MotionEvent, float, float)
```

but you'll probably find there are more once that's done.

If you don't immediately understand the above, then rather than trying to repair the symptoms as they manifest, you should first do some reading around inheritance and interfaces in Java and OOP. You could start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Remove `implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
  GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener`, or
- Implement the methods required by [the `OnGestureListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) and [the `OnDoubleTapListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html) interfaces

As it stands, you have said "yes, Java, I will implement all of the methods required by those two interfaces"... without actually implementing all of the methods required by those two interfaces.

You can read more about Java interfaces in [the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to implement the onFling method.

Try this code:

```
package com.example.gonzales.gestures;

import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

//the error is because of this
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFling(MotionEvent,MotionEvent,float,float){
        //Do stuff with your fling event
    }
}
```